# Extracting a debounce function from a keydown event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a table where rows can be selected using up/down arrows and when a row is selected this goes off and gets the record via ajax.

To stop users spamming ajax requests I have a debounce function that I am calling from a directive. This is triggered through a keydown event. This all works but not the way I need it to. I want the preventDefault to be called before the debounce function is called. So a user can still move up/down rows without the delay and the ajax still only fires after the delay.

I think I need to extract my code out a to allow for this but after trying a few things I can't get it working. This is the original version:

In the directive:

```
$('table').keydown(scope.debounce(function (e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 38) { // Up arrow
        // Do Ajax stuff

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 40) { // Down arrow
        // Do Ajax stuff

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

}, 250));
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.debounce = function (fn, delay) {
    var timer = null;

    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            fn.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
    };
};
```

I have tried extracting the function that gets called on keydown but now it's just ignoring the delay. Can't get my head around how to get it working. This is what I have so far:

In the controller:

```
$('table').keydown(someFunction);

function someFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var blahblah = scope.debounce(function (e) {

        if(e.keyCode == 38) { // Up arrow
            // Do Ajax stuff
        }

        if(e.keyCode == 40) { // Down arrow
            // Do Ajax stuff
        }

    }, 250);

    blahblah();
}
```

Comment: instead of var timer= null , you can use var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            fn.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
    };

Comment: Don't fully understand what you mean but have replaced the code as you say and it doesn't work.

Comment: @ReSedano Hi, ah sorry, I didn't get a response from anyone so decided to take it down. Other than the complex conditionals I didn't really come up with anything else and due to time restraints I've just left it as is for now. I did start to experiment with filling the arrays with all filters by default like this https://codepen.io/jathon77/pen/QWWeqGX which might be a different approach. Problem is when you come off of having 'all' selected on a menu it should only select the one you click on not highlight the remaining items too.

Comment: @ReSedano I have undeleted the other question if you're interested, thanks

Comment: @spengos I found a different approch for your previous question (the codepen you posted now is little different and I can't re-transform all my code, but maybe it can be useful for you). I didn't still reply 'cause your problem was interesting, but to write something else it took me a while. Today I will reply you, I promise. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like every time keydown is pressed, `someFunction` is called and it creates **a new debounced wrapper called blahblah** only to be used exactly once.

Each of these debouncers get called once per keydown stroke, so nothing really get debounced, and everything gets delayed by 250 ms.

You should define `blahblah` outside of `someFunction` and that should fix your timing problem. Don't forget to pass the event object to `blahblah`.

```
$('table').keydown(someFunction);

var blahblah = scope.debounce(function (e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 38) { // Up arrow
        // Do Ajax stuff
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 40) { // Down arrow
        // Do Ajax stuff
    }
}, 250);

function someFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    blahblah(e);
}
```

Also, there is an additional problem but the solution above should have taken care of it. For completeness, I'd like to point it out. The way `someFunction` is written in the OP, you have a name shadowing problem. Let's rename blahblah's parameter e to demonstrate the point:

```
var blahblah = scope.debounce(function (innerE) {

    if(innerE.keyCode == 38) { // Up arrow
        // Do Ajax stuff
    }

    if(innerE.keyCode == 40) { // Down arrow
        // Do Ajax stuff
    }

}, 250);
```

Because of this, when you subsequently call `blahblah()` without passing in an event object, `innerE` is undefined. It's not the event object `e` of the outer scope.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Looks so simple now :)  I just couldn't get my head around it. I needed to extract it into two functions instead of just one.

And yeah there was a small error in my original code. It was supposed to be blahblah(e); I missed out the 'e' when typing it out.

Comment: Glad I helped. I know the feeling of trying to debug timing issues. It seems debounce, throttle, and other timing problems become more convoluted the more you focus on it. The right "solution" is to walk away from these problems for a while. I'm sure if I didn't answer and you look at this again tomorrow, the solution will jump out at you too :)